Can't install updates - error with dependencies
as first thing I wish to excuse me in advance for any error, English is not my first language.
I've tried to follow this post, but I didn't solve the problem.
I'm a (very) junior System Administrator and I'm experiencing issues with applying updated patches on X virtual machines with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) with only command line.
First, I use this:
apt update
Then:
apt upgrade
And that's how I made patching during these last months.
But today the shell gave me this error:
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-196-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-192-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-192-generic but it is not installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-192-generic but it is not installed
 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-196-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.4.0-196-generic but it is not installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-196-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)./var/cache/apt/archives


I searched in this path:
/var/cache/apt/archives
That's what's inside:
linux-modules-5.4.0-192-generic_5.4.0-192.212_amd64.deb  
linux-image-5.4.0-196-generic_5.4.0-196.216_amd64.deb  
linux-modules-5.4.0-196-generic_5.4.0-196.216_amd64.deb

How can I fix this in order to install updates?
And how can I install ony security updates?
Thanks to everyone for your availability.
